# CXF service call failing with unmarshalling error on unexpected namespace

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I'm running into a problem with CXF (2.7.18) all of a sudden. I'm running under Tomcat 8.0.28 and JDK 1.8.0_66.

The issue is that recently we started seeing problems where it would not accept service calls with appropriate headers. The rub is that it works on some systems but not others.

The failure presents as follows:

```
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.namedomain.com", local:"loginRequest"). Expected elements are &lt;{https://www.namedomain.com}loginRequest>
```

Please note that the unexpected element is the correctly namespaced element. The "Expected" elements are incorrect - CXF or something else in the pipeline is remapping the namespace URI to 'https'

Any clue what might be causing this and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the problem. This is an oddity that never surfaced in our prior testing.

Here is the general summary. The application in question utilizing this WSDL generates the binding from the definition and places it in package 'com.foo'.

The application is also dependent on another WSDL endpoint but that module was built separately but had a colliding package name 'com.foo'.

In our prior testing, this never surfaced.

At some point, while migrating to Java 8 & Tomcat 8, this problem surfaced intermittently on certain boxes but not others. Something about the VM image we are using influences the load order. That is not to say that we are dependent on load order, but we just never saw the collision.

Both the external library and the application library had a package-info.java that had conflicting namespace definitions for the XmlSchema annotation. The load order "changed" at some point under Java 8 / Tomcat 8 making the collision evident. The first package-info loaded is cached causing the error.

The solution is to alter the application's generation of the WSDL binding code to put it in another package and avoid the collision.